# docker psql command won't work

Tags: postgresql, docker, psql

I'm trying to use the below command in order to establish db in the docker terminal:

```
psql -h 192.168.99.100 -p 15432 -U postgres
```

However, I receive the following error:bash: psql: command not found

Can you please help me understand what might the problem be?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What "docker terminal"?

Comment: docker quickstart terminal

Comment: How are you opening this terminal? Have you installed psql in the container that this terminal runs in?

Comment: yes using : docker ps  command I can see the psql container running. The terminal is basically an interactive shell

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to execute this command inside the container and not your terminal itself

```
docker exec -it <postgres_container_id_or_name> psql -h 192.168.99.100 -p 15432 -U postgres
```